# Multiple charactor match with LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I need to return the rows that contain both `_1` and `_2` from the SQL Server table. Below is my query and it returns the rows even both the above conditions are not matched.

As per my knowledge, I can use `[` and `]` to match multiple values when using the `LIKE` clause with wild cards.

```
DECLARE @TempTable AS TABLE (Col VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES
('001098E2-5995-446F-87DC-BE71D2B30D37_2|69FA4BCD-C90B-4375-B08C-B3615C55500D_2'),
('0025F9BF-995D-4C88-BBD6-4C707A88BC32_1|F53668A8-F819-4309-BC0C-8DE4C2637419_2'),
('007BB00A-3B69-45FC-A265-1EC8B00E011A_2|0701649E-8BFE-4B03-8456-51E2D9169BD5_2|08950E50-80B2-4BDF-9FC7-3AB0AA4587AE_1')

SELECT * FROM @TempTable
WHERE (Col LIKE '%[_1]%' AND Col LIKE '%[_2]%')
```

I expect not to return `001098E2-5995-446F-87DC-BE71D2B30D37_2|69FA4BCD-C90B-4375-B08C-B3615C55500D_2`, but SQL Server returns all 3 records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM @TempTable
WHERE (Col LIKE '%[_]1%' AND Col LIKE '%[_]2%')
```

[Using Wildcard Characters As Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals)

> You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal characters. To use a wildcard character as a literal character, enclose the wildcard character in brackets. The following table shows several examples of using the LIKE keyword and the [ ] wildcard characters.

Comment: @GuidoG,  I decided to post it because at the moment your version was `[\\_]` with unnecessary \\

Answer (score 3):

You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal characters.
To use a wildcard character as a literal character, enclose the wildcard character in brackets.

```
WHERE (Col LIKE '%[_]1%' AND Col LIKE '%[_]2%')
```

you can also escape the underscore like this

```
WHERE (Col LIKE '%$_1%' ESCAPE '$') 
AND   (Col LIKE '%$_2%' ESCAPE '$')
```

Answer (score 3):

`_` is also a wildcard matching one arbitrary character. You can define an `ESCAPE` character and escape it to match a regular underscore. You don't need `[]`, i.e. character classes here.

```
SELECT *
       FROM @temptable
       WHERE col LIKE '%\_1%' ESCAPE '\'
             AND col LIKE '%\_2%'  ESCAPE '\';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6af6cb36e231d3ca13305e6b42ca4e53)